# Anyone using JRuby testing framework for Eclipse/Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, jruby

I'm not having much luck searching google for this - are there any JRuby unit testing frameworks for Java code that integrate with Eclipse or Maven?  Is there perhaps a Cucumber flavor that integrates with Eclipse, and if so, could someone point me to a quickstart guide explaining how to do it? :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [cucumber-jvm](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm) (previously cuke4duke)? From the project README:

> Cucumber-JVM is a pure Java implementation of Cucumber that supports the following programming languages:
>
> - Clojure
> - Groovy
> - Ioke
> - Java
> - JavaScript (Rhino interpreter)
> - Python (Jython interpreter)
> - Ruby (JRuby interpreter)
> - Scala
>
> Cucumber-JVM provides the following mechanisms for running Cucumber Features:
>
> - Command Line
> - JUnit (via IDE, Maven, Ant or anything that knows how to run JUnit)

We've been using it in our CI builds with Maven and it works great. It looks like you can also write your tests in JRuby.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I'd actually "discovered" BDD-ing in JTestR (http://jtestr.codehaus.org/Getting+Started) a while back, using the very simple _dust_ DSL, which might be interesting to you as well. You pay for the simplicity by having a slightly more painful one-time setup of your pom though. :-)